If $\limsup \frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n}=1$ a.s., is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[\lvert X_n\rvert>n]<\infty$?
Let $\left\lbrace X_n \right\rbrace_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of iid random variables. If $\limsup \frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n}=1$ with probability $1$, is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[\lvert X_n\rvert>n]<\infty$?
My attempt:
I have a problem that asks me to prove that if $\limsup \frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n}\leq 1$ with probability $1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[\lvert X_n\rvert>n]<\infty$. By Borel-Cantelli Lemma, the last inequality is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}[\lvert X_n\rvert>n \,\,i.o.]=0$. Now,
$$
\mathbb{P}[\lvert X_n\rvert>n \,\,i.o.] = \mathbb{P}\left[ \frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n}>1 \,\,i.o.\right]\leq \mathbb{P}\left[\limsup \frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n}\geq 1\right] = \mathbb{P}\left[\limsup \frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n}= 1\right],
$$
where the last equality follows from the hypothesis $\limsup \frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n}\leq 1$ with probability $1$.
Since $\left\lbrace X_n \right\rbrace_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are independent, the same is true for $\left\lbrace \frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n} \right\rbrace_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Therefore, $\limsup \frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n}$ is constant a.e. If that constant is different from $1$, we are done, but I'm having trouble when that constant is $1$. Can anyone provide me some help, please?
Related questions: There are many questions asking to prove the converse, such as
this one. However, I haven't found a proof for the one I'm asking.

I don't think you mean i.i.d. In the i.i.d. case $\lim \sup \frac {|X_n|}n$ would be a.s $0$ if $\sum P(|X_n| >n)<\infty$.

Actually, I'm trying to prove that if $\limsup \frac{\lvert X_n\rvert}{n}= 1$, then the last series converges.

My argument shows that it canot converge.

Can you provide me with a proof or example, please?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[\lvert X_n\rvert>n]<\infty$ iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[\lvert X_1\rvert>n]<\infty$ iff $E|X_1|<\infty$. If this holds, then SLLN shows that $\frac {S_n} n \to 0$ a.s. and this implies (by an elmentary Calculus argument) that $\frac {|X_n|} n$ to a.s., contradicting your hypothesis. Conclusion: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[\lvert X_n\rvert>n]<\infty$ cannot be true.

See that $E(|X_{1}|)=\int_{0}^{\infty}P(|X_{1}|>t)\,dt<\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_{1}|>n)<\infty$
As $\{X_{i}\}$'s are identically distriuted, we have $P(|X_{1}|>n)=P(|X_{n}|>n)$ and hence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_{1}|>n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_{n}|>n)$
Assume that $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|X_{n}|}{n}=1$ a.s.
Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_{n}|>n)<\infty$. Then this means $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|X_{1}|>n)<\infty\implies E(|X_{1}|)<\infty$
Thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(|\frac{|X_{n}|}{n}|>\epsilon)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(\frac{|X_{1}|}{\epsilon}>n)<\infty$ as $E(\frac{|X_{1}|}{\epsilon})<\infty$ and this holds for all fixed $\epsilon>0$
Thus, the Borel Cantelli Lemma now tells you that $\frac{|X_{n}|}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0$ which contradicts our assumption that $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|X_{n}|}{n}=1$ a.s.
